# Output running services to csv with computer name

Tags: powershell

I need to generate a csv containing running services to csv with the corresponding computer name
I know there is a simple way to do this and I have been tinkering with creating a new psobject, but I am not sure how to pipe the results to the new-object...

Here is what I am using:

```
$Input = "SomePath"
$Output = "SomeOtherPath"
$CompNames = Get-Content -Path "$Input"

ForEach ($CompName in $CompNames){
Get-Service -ComputerName $CompName | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Export-csv -Path "$Output"
}
```

What I need in the CSV is:

ComputerName, ServiceName, DisplayName

basically, I need to add the computer name to the array.

Comment: DO NOT use `$Input` as a variable name ... it is an automatic $Var and will be changed whenever PoSh want to do so. treat it [and all other auto-vars] as Read-Only objects. [*grin*]

Comment: to add details to your CSV ... build an object that has the desired properties. i would build a `[PSCustomObject]`, but many folks seem to prefer using `Select-Object` and calculated properties.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking PSCustomObject as well, but wasn't sure how to use it properly. My attempts at using Select-Object were ... not successful.

Comment: it looks like you have two nifty examples of the `Select-Object` technique, so i will wander off without posting yet another Answer. glad that you got things working as needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to pipe the results, use a foreach-object.

```
$Output = "SomeOtherPath"

Get-Content -Path "SomePath" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $_ | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select-Object ComputerName, ServiceName, DisplayName
} | Export-csv -Path "$Output"
```

If you want to stick to a foreach statement, collect it all first then export it.

```
$Output = "SomeOtherPath"
$CompNames = Get-Content -Path "SomePath"

$results = ForEach ($CompName in $CompNames){
    Get-Service -ComputerName $CompName | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select-Object ComputerName, ServiceName, DisplayName
}

$results | Export-csv -Path "$Output"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this (Don't use $Input as variable name)

```
$InputX = "SomePath"
$Output = "SomeOtherPath"
$CompNames = Get-Content -Path "$Input"

ForEach ($CompName in $CompNames){
Get-Service -ComputerName $CompName | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select-Object ComputerName, ServiceName, DisplayName |  Export-csv -Path "$Output"
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I just need to change ComputerName to MachineName, but basically, it worked.
     $InputX = "SomePath"
     $Output = "SomeOtherPath"
     $CompNames = Get-Content -Path "$Input"

     ForEach ($CompName in $CompNames){
     Get-Service -ComputerName $CompName | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} |  
     Select-Object ComputerName, ServiceName, DisplayName |  Export-csv -Path "$Output"
     }

Comment: I tried this, it returns what I would expect if I send it to the console, but when I pipe it to the export-csv, nothing is captured....

Comment: I got it, I need to add -append -notype